# How to add Firebase into android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want added **Firebase** into my application. I write below codes, but when running application I can't see **TOKEN** in log!

My dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest :

```
<application>
...
        <!--Firebase service-->
        <service android:name=".CloudMSG.MyFirebaseInctanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
```

**MyFirebaseInctanceIdService :**

```
public class MyFirebaseInctanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseInctance";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("MyFirebaseInctance", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        //sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

**Logs:**

```
03-30 13:36:42.943 9487-9487/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-30 13:36:43.218 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
03-30 13:36:43.269 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10004
03-30 13:36:43.298 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
03-30 13:36:43.364 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10084
03-30 13:36:43.364 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
03-30 13:36:43.364 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
03-30 13:36:43.364 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase D/FA: AppMeasurement singleton hash: 720240273
03-30 13:36:43.404 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase V/FA: Collection enabled
03-30 13:36:43.404 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase V/FA: App package, google app id: com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase, 1:685652680518:android:0280a3bc1c6da8cb
03-30 13:36:43.405 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase
03-30 13:36:43.463 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
03-30 13:36:43.465 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
03-30 13:36:43.467 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase
03-30 13:36:43.471 9487-9587/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase V/FA: Using measurement service
03-30 13:36:43.489 9487-9587/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase V/FA: Connecting to remote service
03-30 13:36:43.528 9487-9587/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 6599430
03-30 13:36:43.612 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase D/ContextHelper: convertTheme. context->name=com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase themeResourceId=2131230883
03-30 13:36:43.656 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-30 13:36:43.690 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase V/FA: onActivityCreated
03-30 13:36:43.696 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
03-30 13:36:43.718 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xfff5f5f5
03-30 13:36:43.718 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x fff5f5f5
03-30 13:36:43.859 9487-9587/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase V/FA: Using measurement service
03-30 13:36:43.859 9487-9587/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
03-30 13:36:43.864 9487-9587/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1436094125
03-30 13:36:43.879 9487-9612/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
03-30 13:36:43.881 9487-9612/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.013_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                            OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
                                                                            Build Date: 01/21/15 Wed
                                                                            Local Branch: mybranch7061829
                                                                            Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.7
                                                                            Local Patches: NONE
                                                                            Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.013 +  NOTHING
03-30 13:36:43.882 9487-9612/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-30 13:36:43.910 9487-9612/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-30 13:36:43.916 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase D/Atlas: Validating map...
03-30 13:36:43.927 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
03-30 13:36:43.936 9487-9592/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase D/FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, retry in 30s
03-30 13:36:44.008 9487-9502/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.068ms
03-30 13:36:44.047 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
03-30 13:36:44.183 9487-9487/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@755dbad time:128236912
03-30 13:37:14.017 9487-10051/com.example.mohammad.a1_firebase D/FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, retry in 60s
```

How can I fix this issue and show Firebase token in logs?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase `onTokenRefresh()` will only be called if your token changes. Before that you should invoke

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
```

in your initial activity (like MainActivity) maybe.

Comment: I try this code and not show me again :( why show me this message in log : Service connection failed: `ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}`   how can I fix it?

Comment: And please see this log : `FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, retry in 60s`  how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

why you not tried integrated android studio with firebase directly using Tools menu-->firebase

add this line Gradle :-Module(app)

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
```

Comment: I use your above way and add this files when use menu-->firebase! but not show me token! how can I fix? can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

> Try to uninstall the application and re-install , you will see the
>   Refreshed token in the logcat.
>
> Also check in firebase console that Anonymous sign-in status is
>   Enabled or not in Authentication menu -> Sign in method

Comment: I uninstall and re-install but not show me again :(

Comment: See in Firebase console for sign in status . Enable it and then check it.

Comment: How can I enable this? can you show me this path? please

Comment: Go to your Firebase console
https://console.firebase.google.com
You see Authentication menu in left side
There are 3 tabs ( Users , Sign in method, Email Templates )
Go to Sign in method and enabeld Anonymous Provider